How can I create a wrinkled cloth style frame?
I am trying to create a wrinkled cloth style frame, and I want to know how I would even start something like this. I already have a base shape for it and subdivided it, but I am very new to work with cloth style mesh.
This is a reference picture in what I would like to achieve.


You could create a plane, subdivide it, switch to Sculpt mode, choose the Pose brush, Deformation Target: Cloth Simulation, Deformation: Squash & Stretch:

Increase the brush size with F then LMB and drag:

Duplicate and merge the vertices so that it gives a long plane, or bake its normals to use it as a normal map on a low-poly mesh:


Amazing thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I got it to work flawlessly, Now how would i create a frame out of it just like in the picture?

you can duplicate the mesh, or bake its normals to use it as a normal map on a low-poly mesh?
